# how to ensure unique id for each currently running client as well as ensure that each id matches pattern

Tags: java

So say you have a networking program in java in which the server is serving multiple clients at once, and the way each client accesses their information is simply by typing in their id. Before the server starts the thread for the client, you want it to make sure that the id typed in by the user once the client program begins to run isn't already being used by a thread that's currently running, and that it matches a specific pattern (say 4 digits). The way I've approached this is by having the server class declare and initialize an arraylist for the ids of the currently running threads before it does anything, use a regular expression to check if the the id is 4 digits long, and if it is then check to see if the id is in the arraylist, and if it isn't then the thread can begin. Code shown below:

```
   while(true)
  {
     ClientWorker w;
     try
     {
        w = new ClientWorker(server.accept());
        String validid = w.accountnumber;
        if(validid.matches("\\d[4]"))
        {
             if(!currentusers.contains(validid))
             {
                currentusers.add(validid);
                Thread t = new Thread(w);
                t.start();
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Already in session");
             }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("not a valid id");
        }
 }
```

The problem is that neither of my objectives are ever accomplished and it just causes errors to a previously working program: regardless of what id i type in, the client continues along just fine and asks me what transactions i want to undertake. Then if I try to actually do anything the server program crashes and gives me null pointer exceptions when I try to match the regex in the if statement and when i tell the server to listen to the port corresponding to the client socket in the main method. I think the problem is that I can't figure out a way to get the id of the client before the thread starts, because it seems to me that the thread has to start before the user can type in their id, which creates a circle that I have to square. Can anyone help me out with this? PS: the clientworker class accepts a socket as a parameter for its constructor and assigns it to a socket reference that's already been declared in case that confuses anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm should be:

```
while (true)
    accept a new client
    start a thread to communicate with the client
```

And the thread should do:

```
read the ID sent by the client
check if it's valid and add it to a set of IDs if not already present
if invalid or already present
    send an error message to the client
    stop running
else 
    continue the conversation with the client. 
    once the conversation ends, in a finally block, remove the ID from the set of IDs
```

You should use a HashSet rather than a List, since it's much faster at lookups (O(1)), and you should make sure that the methods `checkIfIdPresentAndIfItDoesntThenAddTheId()` and `removeId()` are properly synchronized, since the set is accessed by multiple threads.